# SVG text not aligned correctly on edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, microsoft-edge

I have created an SVG with a base64 background image and two text areas (top and bottom text). These text areas can be updated via two input forms.

This functions correctly apart from on Internet Explorer and Edge, whereby the bottom text is aligned to the left instead of the center and the position of the bottom text is also incorrect. Top text is displaying correctly.

I am currently only trying to resolve this issue for Edge. If you view the link below I have a demo of the SVG and two fields.

https://jsfiddle.net/znhs955p/1/

For excepted behavior view on chrome or firefox.

```
<text
    xml:space="preserve"
    style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12.58850098px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:2px;word-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1.43085253"
    id="bottom"
    transform="matrix(0.91651557,0,0,0.91221872,8.953221,18.767226)"
    x="1.5895385"
    y="3.9430504">

    <textPath
        xlink:href="#ellipse4592"
        startOffset="50%"
        id="bottom-text"
        style="font-size:21px;letter-spacing:2px;stroke-width:1.43085253">
            Bottom Text
    </textPath>
</text>


<text
    id="text4630"
    style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:13.35012245px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1.66707253"
    xml:space="preserve"
    transform="matrix(-0.90287605,0,0,-0.90624359,513.44619,329.63062)">

    <textPath
        xlink:href="#path5204"
        startOffset="50%"
        id="top-text"
        style="font-size:18px;stroke-width:1.66707253">
            Top Text
    </textPath>
</text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `x` and `y` attributes from the `<text>` element that wraps your `<textPath>`.

I.e. change:

```
<text ...
      x="1.5895385"
      y="3.9430504">
  <textPath ... id="bottom-text" ...>Bottom Text</textPath>
</text>
```

to

```
<text ...>
  <textPath ... id="bottom-text" ...>Bottom Text</textPath>
</text>
```

Those `x` and `y` attributes seem to be confusing IE.

https://jsfiddle.net/znhs955p/2/